# Applying for "Aufenthaltsbewilligung – Familiengemeinschaft" from within Austria

Tags: austria, residency

I am Iranian and I am going to reunite with my husband (he is Iranian and staying in Vienna under "Forscher=researcher" residence permit) who works as a researcher in Vienna (stay more than six months). It is recommended that I apply for the residence permit "Aufenthaltsbewilligung – Familiengemeinschaft". I am wondering if it is possible that I first obtain a tourist visa for Austria and when I arrived there, then I apply for the above mentioned residence permit  from**within** Austria? That is, is it legally possible to apply for "Aufenthaltsbewilligung – Familiengemeinschaft" from within Austria?

Comment: What is the nationality of your husband, and what visa/permit/etc is he in Austria on?

Comment: @Gagravarr I edited the question to answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a government site (http://www.migration.gv.at/en/types-of-immigration/temporary-residence.html), "Foreign citizens applying for a residence permit as a researcher and their family members" may "file first applications in Austria" for the residence permit.

Presumably you should seek further information from the institution hosting your husband or from the Austrian consulate in Tehran: http://www.bmeia.gv.at/botschaft/teheran.html

(If you are not *in* Iran, then you should look for the Austrian consulate in the country where you are.)